# GGeoXml error with Arcgis extension for google maps api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps

I'm using the ArcGis google maps extension.

I've created a simple page based on the esri example [here...](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/gmaps/help/google_start.htm)

I have successfully buffered a polyline, however, when I create a query and execute the related queryTask, I see the following error...(in Firebug)

**"GGeoXml object could not load the KML file correctly"**

as a rough guess, I'd say there's a problem with my proxy setup, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

im quoting from [Esri Forum](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=204&f=2388&t=255342):

> To load KML in Google Maps your server
>   must be publically accessible. If your
>   server is on your local network then
>   you cannot use that option.